# NPE in DataSource object

Tags: jakarta-ee, shiro

I would like to use Apache Shiro in a Java EE application. I tried this custom realm:

```
 public class JdbcRealm extends AuthorizingRealm implements Serializable
{
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/DefaultDB")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    protected static final String DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY = "select passwd from user where username = ?";
    protected static final String DEFAULT_SALTED_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY = "select passwd, passwd_salt from user where username = ?";
    protected static final String DEFAULT_USER_ROLES_QUERY = "select role_name from user_roles where username = ?";
    protected static final String DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_QUERY = "select permission from roles_permissions where role_name = ?";
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JdbcRealm.class);

    public enum SaltStyle
    {
        NO_SALT, CRYPT, COLUMN, EXTERNAL
    };

    protected String authenticationQuery = DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY;
    protected String userRolesQuery = DEFAULT_USER_ROLES_QUERY;
    protected String permissionsQuery = DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_QUERY;
    protected boolean permissionsLookupEnabled = false;

    protected SaltStyle saltStyle = SaltStyle.NO_SALT;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationQuery(String authenticationQuery)
    {
        this.authenticationQuery = authenticationQuery;
    }

    public void setUserRolesQuery(String userRolesQuery)
    {
        this.userRolesQuery = userRolesQuery;
    }

    public void setPermissionsQuery(String permissionsQuery)
    {
        this.permissionsQuery = permissionsQuery;
    }

    public void setPermissionsLookupEnabled(boolean permissionsLookupEnabled)
    {
        this.permissionsLookupEnabled = permissionsLookupEnabled;
    }

    public void setSaltStyle(SaltStyle saltStyle)
    {
        this.saltStyle = saltStyle;
        if (saltStyle == SaltStyle.COLUMN && authenticationQuery.equals(DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY))
        {
            authenticationQuery = DEFAULT_SALTED_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        String username = upToken.getUsername();
        // Null username is invalid
        if (username == null)
        {
            throw new AccountException("Null usernames are not allowed by this realm.");
        }
        Connection conn = null;
        SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = null;
        try
        {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            String password = null;
            String salt = null;
            switch (saltStyle)
            {
                case NO_SALT:
                    password = getPasswordForUser(conn, username)[0];
                    break;
                case CRYPT:
                    // TODO: separate password and hash from getPasswordForUser[0]
                    throw new ConfigurationException("Not implemented yet");
                //break;
                case COLUMN:
                    String[] queryResults = getPasswordForUser(conn, username);
                    password = queryResults[0];
                    salt = queryResults[1];
                    break;
                case EXTERNAL:
                    password = getPasswordForUser(conn, username)[0];
                    salt = getSaltForUser(username);
            }
            if (password == null)
            {
                throw new UnknownAccountException("No account found for user [" + username + "]");
            }
            info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, password.toCharArray(), getName());

            if (salt != null)
            {
                info.setCredentialsSalt(ByteSource.Util.bytes(salt));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            final String message = "There was a SQL error while authenticating user [" + username + "]";
            if (log.isErrorEnabled())
            {
                log.error(message, e);
            }
            // Rethrow any SQL errors as an authentication exception
            throw new AuthenticationException(message, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            JdbcUtils.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        return info;
    }

    private String[] getPasswordForUser(Connection conn, String username) throws SQLException
    {
        String[] result;
        boolean returningSeparatedSalt = false;
        switch (saltStyle)
        {
            case NO_SALT:
            case CRYPT:
            case EXTERNAL:
                result = new String[1];
                break;
            default:
                result = new String[2];
                returningSeparatedSalt = true;
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try
        {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(authenticationQuery);
            ps.setString(1, username);
            // Execute query
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            // Loop over results - although we are only expecting one result, since usernames should be unique
            boolean foundResult = false;
            while (rs.next())
            {
                // Check to ensure only one row is processed
                if (foundResult)
                {
                    throw new AuthenticationException("More than one user row found for user [" + username + "]. Usernames must be unique.");
                }
                result[0] = rs.getString(1);
                if (returningSeparatedSalt)
                {
                    result[1] = rs.getString(2);
                }
                foundResult = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals)
    {
        //null usernames are invalid
        if (principals == null)
        {
            throw new AuthorizationException("PrincipalCollection method argument cannot be null.");
        }
        String username = (String) getAvailablePrincipal(principals);
        Connection conn = null;
        Set<String> roleNames = null;
        Set<String> permissions = null;
        try
        {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            // Retrieve roles and permissions from database
            roleNames = getRoleNamesForUser(conn, username);
            if (permissionsLookupEnabled)
            {
                permissions = getPermissions(conn, username, roleNames);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            final String message = "There was a SQL error while authorizing user [" + username + "]";
            if (log.isErrorEnabled())
            {
                log.error(message, e);
            }
            // Rethrow any SQL errors as an authorization exception
            throw new AuthorizationException(message, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            JdbcUtils.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo(roleNames);
        info.setStringPermissions(permissions);
        return info;
    }

    protected Set<String> getRoleNamesForUser(Connection conn, String username) throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Set<String> roleNames = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        try
        {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(userRolesQuery);
            ps.setString(1, username);
            // Execute query
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            // Loop over results and add each returned role to a set
            while (rs.next())
            {
                String roleName = rs.getString(1);
                // Add the role to the list of names if it isn't null
                if (roleName != null)
                {
                    roleNames.add(roleName);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (log.isWarnEnabled())
                    {
                        log.warn("Null role name found while retrieving role names for user [" + username + "]");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
        }
        return roleNames;
    }

    protected Set<String> getPermissions(Connection conn, String username, Collection<String> roleNames) throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Set<String> permissions = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        try
        {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(permissionsQuery);
            for (String roleName : roleNames)
            {
                ps.setString(1, roleName);
                ResultSet rs = null;
                try
                {
                    // Execute query
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    // Loop over results and add each returned role to a set
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        String permissionString = rs.getString(1);
                        // Add the permission to the set of permissions
                        permissions.add(permissionString);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
        }
        return permissions;
    }

    protected String getSaltForUser(String username)
    {
        return username;
    }
}
```

But I get NPE in this line:

```
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

As you can see I get data source via annotation `@Resource(name = "jdbc/DefaultDB")`. I suspect that this annotation is initialized after Java method `getRoleNamesForUser`. IS there any way to call the annotation before `getRoleNamesForUser`?

Comment: How is this jsf related? Other then you using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are just metadata. You need something to process this metadata for you. In Java EE envoronment it's usually an EJB container who does it, but even there only session beans' injections are processed by container. You may use an embedded EJB container for that purposes, but this would definitely be an overkill.

Shiro is not an EJB container, it's just a security manager. However, it provides some restricted dependency injection capabilities itself. [Here](http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-%5Cmain%5C) is a wider explanation of what Shiro has to offer. In your particular case you may define your DataSource as a Shiro's internal object factory in your ini configuration:

```
[main]
dataSource = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
dataSource.resourceName = jdbc/DefaultDB
```

And then use it like:

```
jdbcRealm = path.to.clazz.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource
```

Comment: For some reason when I added these lines in Shiro.ini I get meesage FAIL - Deployed application at context path

Comment: This message tells nothing useful, consider inspecting more verbose logs to find out actual failure reason.